# The method onPause( ), onResume( ) is undefined for the type

Tags: android, android-sensors, onresume, onpause, sensormanager

I a have class for ShakeListener and i have implemented onPause() and onResume() methods in that. My code for that is

```
package com.example.shakedemo;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.content.Context;
import java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException;


public class ShakeListener
{
      private SensorManager mSensorManager;
      private float mAccel; // acceleration apart from gravity
      private float mAccelCurrent; // current acceleration including gravity
      private float mAccelLast; // last acceleration including gravity

  private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
      float x = se.values[0];
      float y = se.values[1];
      float z = se.values[2];
      mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
      mAccelCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
      float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
      mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta; // perform low-cut filter
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }


  };



  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);

  }
}
```

But it showing an error on both super.onPause(); and super.onResume(); lines which says

> The method onPause() is undefined for the type   Object

Is there any problem in implementing onResume and onPause in a class?

As i am a new one in android development please give me  clear idea about that.

Comment: post the full class code

Comment: edited now. please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onResume` and `onPause` are the methods of an `Activity` class. You are not overriding the activity.

If the `ShakeListener` is an `Activity` you need to extends the `Activity` class. like

```
public class ShakeListener extends Activity
```

And if that is not an Activity class, then do not call super versions.

Just do them as

```
public void registerListener() {
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  public void unregisterListener() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);

  }
```

Comment: can you please give me the solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your implementations call the `super` versions of the methods which don't exist.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); // <== This line needs to be removed
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause(); // <== This line needs to go as well
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);

}
```

Either get rid of the `super` calls (which makes the most sense) or inherit from a class that implements the methods.

Comment: what is the solution for that?

Comment: @Nitin - I posted your code with comments indicating the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your class a subclass of `Activity` class, So that you can get the `onPause` and `onResume` of the Activity class.

```
public class ShakeListener extends Activity
```

Currently, your class is a subclass of `Object` class which does not have `onResume` and `onPause` method, this is why when you are calling `super.onPause` and `super.onResume`, you are getting the exception.